# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null at HTMLDocument.handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in my Header component. I thought that this might throw this error because I try to access this even before it is rendered on the screen. I am not sure why this does not work, I have tried to use `forwardRef` at the child component and I get the following error at the ref from `SearchDropDown` component. I hope someone could tell me what is wrong here.

```
Type '((instance: unknown) => void) | MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
      Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
        Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 235 more.
The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

Page component

```
  const domNodeRef = useRef(null);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => {
      if (domNodeRef !== undefined || domNodeRef !== null) {
        if (!domNodeRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
          setSearch("");
        }
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);

    return () => {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    };
  });

  return (
   <div className="header">
     <div className="header-content">
       <div className="searchh">
         <input 
           placeholder="Type to search"
           onChange={handleSearchChange}
         />
         {!!search && (
           <SearchDropDown 
             search={search}
             ref={domNodeRef}
           />
         )}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  )
```

SearchDropDown component

```
const SearchDropDown = (props) => {
  ....
  return (
    <div className="search-drop-down" ref={props.ref}>
     .....
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useRef` will return a *consistent object*. It'll never be `null` or `undefined`.

What will change is the `.current` property on the ref - that's what you should check, not the ref object itself.

```
if (domNodeRef !== undefined || domNodeRef !== null) {
```

should be changed to

```
if (domNodeRef.current) {
```

Also

```
return () => {
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
};
```

should be

```
return () => {
  document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
};
```

You might consider another approach though - instead of a ref and `.contains`, just check if the target has a `.closest` element of the search bar:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => {
        if (!e.target.closest('.search-drop-down')) {
            setSearch("");
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    };
}, []);
```